# Is there anything like Spring TestExecutionListener for TestSuite?

Tags: java, spring, junit, testcontext

Currently for tests I'm using `TestExecutionListener` and it works just perfect

```
public class ExecutionManager extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("beforeClass");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("afterClass");
    }
}
```

Test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(ExecutionManager.class)
public final class TC_001 {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test_001");
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(ExecutionManager.class)
public final class TC_002 {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test_002");
    }
}
```

When I include those tests in test suite, `beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext)` and `afterTestClass(TestContext testContext)` methods are executed for each test class, what is quite logical:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        TC_001.class,
        TC_002.class
})
public final class TS_001 {
}
```

Is there anything like `SuiteExecutionListener` (`TestExecutionListener` for suites)?

Basically I need non-static `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` for suite

**OR**

In ExecutionListener I need to find out what class has been launched: case or suite. For this purpose I can:

- analyze `StackTrace` and get calling class
- use `Reflection.getCallerClass(int i)` (which is deprecated)
- pass caller class to `ExecutionManager` (By the way, how can I do that? Is it possible to put `Object` into `TestContext` like in Android `Bundle`?)

But I don't really like those solutions. `SuiteExecutionListener` is much more preferable

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is unfortunately no such thing as a `SuiteExecutionListener` in the *Spring TestContext Framework* (TCF).

The TCF does not integrate with JUnit 4 at the suite level.

If you want to store something in the `TestContext`, that's not a problem. `TestContext` implements `org.springframework.core.AttributeAccessor`, so you can store *attributes* in the `TestContext`. Note, however, that the lifecycle of a given `TestContext` is tied to a test class.

Comment: So basically, if TestContext is tied to a test class, I cannot use it to manage test suite flow from TestExecutionListener because it is going to be different TestContext for each test case. Am I correct?

Comment: In addition, as far as I can see for now, I cannot access TestContext from test suite, but ApplicationContext is available. As it is available, I can put some flag bean there and read it from my ExecutionManager. Theoretically it will allow me to manage test suite flow as ApplicationContext may be cached. It doesn't look good, by I don't see other options considering the additional fact, that I cannot use reflection in ExecutionManager: test suite and test classes are simply absent in stacktrace. Could you give me a clue if there is anything more handy for my purpose? Thank you

Comment: To answer your first question: yes, that's correct. Spring has nothing to do with the JUnit 4 `Suite` runner. So there is no support for `TestExecutionListener`s at the suite level.

Comment: If you want to _manage test suite flow_ (as you call it), you would basically have to extend `org.junit.runners.Suite` and add your custom behavior.

Comment: To communicate between your custom `Suite` implementation and the test classes it runs, you might consider using a `ThreadLocal`. That might be more elegant than reflection or storing some bean in a _potentially_ shared `ApplicationContext`.