# What is the best way for customization of multiple TestExecutionListeners methods invoking for TestSuite?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

For optimizing purpose I need to customize `TestExecutionListeners` invoking logic

In my case I have one `ApplicationContext` and two types of tests:

1. Ones which use `WebDriver` (let’s call it `ObservableTest`)
2. Ones which use `RestTemplate` and `JdbcTemplate` (let’s call it `ApiTest`)

Each type uses its own `TestExecutionListener`:

1. `ObservableTest` - `ObservableTestListener`
2. `ApiTest` - `ApiTestListener`

Both `ObservableTestListener` and `ApiTestListener` extend `TestListener` where `prepareTestInstance()` is defined

`ObservableTestListener` implements `beforeTestClass()` and `afterTestClass()` methods as well as `ApiTestListener` does

I need combine test types above in one `JUnit TestSuite` in the next way:

1. For each test `prepareTestInstance()` is invoked
2. As soon as first `ObservableTest` is about to be instantiated, `beforeTestClass()` of `ObservableTestListener` is executed
3. The same with `ApiTest`
4. `afterTestClass()` of `ObservableTestListener` is invoked when last `ObservableTest` is finished in current Suite
5. The same with `ApiTest`

Things got even more complicated as each test may be run in one suite and in different `ApplicationContexts` (due to different profiles usage)

I would be very grateful for any hint and digging direction to implement such logic properly

I have two ideas so far:

1. Implementing custom `Runner` (I'm not confident it is even possible)
2. Notify `TestContextManager` somehow that particular method (`beforeTestClass()` or `afterTestClass()`) should or should not be invoked. I have a feeling that <strike>`@BootstrapWith`</strike> custom `SpringClassRule` should help me in that

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't it possible to use `@TestExecutionListeners` on the 2 different test types to register the appropriate listeners?

Comment: @M.Deinum this is exactly what I am doing, but when I put those test in suite, TestExecutionListeners invoke its methods with each test of this suite. I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: Spring's SuiteExecutionListener may work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985717/is-there-anything-like-spring-testexecutionlistener-for-testsuite

Answer (score 1):

The `TestExecutionListener` API in the Spring TestContext Framework does not have any lifecycle callbacks at the suite level.

Thus, out of the box, there is no way to instruct Spring to invoke methods on TELs before or after a suite. Consequently, any solution you come up with to support your requirements will have to be completely custom.

I don't foresee how a custom `SpringClassRule` would be that useful: you will still need some reliable mechanism for determining when a test suite begins and ends. That is actually the biggest challenge since suite support in JUnit 4 is via a specific `Runner`. So, if you run all of your tests via a JUnit 4 `Suite`, you could potentially build in your own lifecycle callbacks in a custom subclass of `Suite`.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)